# bash script to upload files to a FTP server

Tags: bash, loops, ftp

I have a script that uploads several files to a FTP. The script shall work in 5 min loop (upload files every 5 minutes).
It seems the script only uploads the files for the first time. The script stays in a loop and does not exit but the files are not copied any more.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
HOST='my host'
USER='my user name'
PASSWD='my password'
FILE1='file1.txt'
FILE2='file2.txt'
FILE3='file3.txt'
FILE4='file4.txt'
FILE5='file5.txt'

while true
do
ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
binary
put $FILE1
put $FILE2
put $FILE3
put $FILE4
put $FILE5
quit
END_SCRIPT
sleep 300
done
exit 0
```

To run the script, I use

```
nohup ./upload_data.sh &
```

Comment: Btw.: `sh` is not `bash`.

Comment: Your loop is "putting" the same files. If they should be updated, you probably need to remove them from the remote side (with `delete`) before your second, and subsequent, puts. `rsync` is probably a better protocol for this.

Comment: Before I "put" the files I do "delete" first. It seems to work better. After few hours, it got stuck again. I'll see over the next days if the reason is elsewhere. Thanks Elliott for the hint.